# Convert from class-based component to functional-based component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use the react-native-maps-directions example found in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps-directions on my project.

Can someone help me convert this code from class base component to functional base component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE = 37.771707;
const LONGITUDE = -122.4053769;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = '…';

class Example extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // AirBnB's Office, and Apple Park
    this.state = {
      coordinates: [
        {
          latitude: 37.3317876,
          longitude: -122.0054812,
        },
        {
          latitude: 37.771707,
          longitude: -122.4053769,
        },
      ],
    };

    this.mapView = null;
  }

  onMapPress = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      coordinates: [
        ...this.state.coordinates,
        e.nativeEvent.coordinate,
      ],
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MapView
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: LATITUDE,
          longitude: LONGITUDE,
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        }}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        ref={c => this.mapView = c}
        onPress={this.onMapPress}
      >
        {this.state.coordinates.map((coordinate, index) =>
          <MapView.Marker key={`coordinate_${index}`} coordinate={coordinate} />
        )}
        {(this.state.coordinates.length >= 2) && (
          <MapViewDirections
            origin={this.state.coordinates[0]}
            waypoints={ (this.state.coordinates.length > 2) ? this.state.coordinates.slice(1, -1): undefined}
            destination={this.state.coordinates[this.state.coordinates.length-1]}
            apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
            strokeWidth={3}
            strokeColor="hotpink"
            optimizeWaypoints={true}
            onStart={(params) => {
              console.log(`Started routing between "${params.origin}" and "${params.destination}"`);
            }}
            onReady={result => {
              console.log(`Distance: ${result.distance} km`)
              console.log(`Duration: ${result.duration} min.`)

              this.mapView.fitToCoordinates(result.coordinates, {
                edgePadding: {
                  right: (width / 20),
                  bottom: (height / 20),
                  left: (width / 20),
                  top: (height / 20),
                }
              });
            }}
            onError={(errorMessage) => {
              // console.log('GOT AN ERROR');
            }}
          />
        )}
      </MapView>
    );
  }
}

export default Example;
```

Can someone help me convert this code from class base component to functional base component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not react native use (i only use the reactjs) but this is my  try it may help (i can't test if it work or not).

```
  import React from 'react'
import { useState ,useRef} from 'react';

import { Dimensions, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import MapViewDirections from 'react-native-maps-directions';



const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const ASPECT_RATIO = width / height;
const LATITUDE = 37.771707;
const LONGITUDE = -122.4053769;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATIO;

const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = '…';


const Example = () => {

    const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([{
        latitude: 37.3317876,
        longitude: -122.0054812,
    },
    {
        latitude: 37.771707,
        longitude: -122.4053769,
    },
    ],)
    let mapView = useRef(null)

    let onMapPress = (e) => {
        setCoordinates((coordinates) =>
            [
                ...coordinates,
                e.nativeEvent.coordinate,
            ],
        );
    }

    return (
        <MapView
        initialRegion={{
            latitude: LATITUDE,
            longitude: LONGITUDE,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
        }}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        ref={c => mapView.current = c}
        onPress={onMapPress}
    >
        {coordinates.map((coordinate, index) =>
            <MapView.Marker key={`coordinate_${index}`} coordinate={coordinate} />
        )}
        {(coordinates.length >= 2) && (
            <MapViewDirections
                origin={coordinates[0]}
                waypoints={(coordinates.length > 2) ? coordinates.slice(1, -1) : undefined}
                destination={coordinates[coordinates.length - 1]}
                apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
                strokeWidth={3}
                strokeColor="hotpink"
                optimizeWaypoints={true}
                onStart={(params) => {
                    console.log(`Started routing between "${params.origin}" and "${params.destination}"`);
                }}
                onReady={result => {
                    console.log(`Distance: ${result.distance} km`)
                    console.log(`Duration: ${result.duration} min.`)

                    mapView.current.fitToCoordinates(result.coordinates, {
                        edgePadding: {
                            right: (width / 20),
                            bottom: (height / 20),
                            left: (width / 20),
                            top: (height / 20),
                        }
                    });
                }}
                onError={(errorMessage) => {
                    // console.log('GOT AN ERROR');
                }}
            />
        )}
    </MapView>
    )
}

export default Example;
```

Comment: oh good to hear that .